# How to get query to show results in columns rather than rows?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following BigQuery query:

```
SELECT avg(order_total)  as currentVal FROM ...

UNION ALL

select AVG(order_total)  as lastVal FROM ...
```

This gives me:

```
Row currentVal  
1    28.50161137440758
2    25.068
```

How can i get it as:

```
Row currentVal          lastVal
1    28.50161137440758  25.068
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subquery & do aggregation :

```
SELECT AVG(currentVal) AS currentVal, AVG(lastVal) AS lastVal
FROM (SELECT order_total AS currentVal, 0 AS lastVal  
      FROM ...
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 0, order_total 
      FROM ...
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when like below

```
    select max(case when row=1 then currentVal end) as currentVal,
            max(case when row=2 then currentVal end) as lastVal  from 
   (
    SELECT 1 as row avg(order_total)  as currentVal FROM ...

    UNION ALL

    select 2 , AVG(order_total)  as lastVal FROM 
  ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using subqueries would be the easiest way to get it.

```
select 
(select AVG(order_total) from ...) as currentVal,
(select  AVG(order_total) from ...) as lastVal
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge sub queries in SELECT gives the worst performance